# Numpy: Get matrices from tensor given list of indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tensor with the shape `(4, 3, 20)`. When I do `X[:, 0, :].shape` I get `(4, 20)`. When I do `X[:, [0,2,0,1], :].shape` I get `(4, 4, 20)`.

What I have is a list of indexes representing the second dimension of my tensor. I want to get a two-dimensional matrix like I get when I do `X[:, 0, :]` but I have different indexes for the second dimension instead of only one. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I'll make a guess

```
In [58]: X=np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)

In [59]: X[range(4),[0,2,0,1],:]
Out[59]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [20, 21]])
```

This picks row 0 from the 1st plane; row 2 from the 2nd, etc.  The result has the same shape as `X[:,0,:]`, but values are pulled from different 1st dimension planes.

```
In [61]: X[:,0,:]
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0,  1],   # same
       [ 6,  7],
       [12, 13],   # same
       [18, 19]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`np.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html). So, for cases when the indexing list, say `L` has just one element and upon indexing the input array with it would result in a `3D` array with a singleton second dimension (dimension of length 1), would result in a `2D` output with that *squeez-ing*. For `L` with more than one element, the indexing would result in a `3D` array without any singleton dimension and thus, no change with that *squeez-ing* and hence the desired output. Thus, the solution with it would be -

```
np.squeeze(X[:,L,:])
```

Sample run to test out shapes on a random array -

```
In [25]: A = np.random.rand(4,3,20)

In [26]: L = [0]

In [27]: np.squeeze(A[:,L,:]).shape
Out[27]: (4, 20)

In [28]: L = [0,2,0,1]

In [29]: np.squeeze(A[:,L,:]).shape
Out[29]: (4, 4, 20)
```